# Application failed to start the method does not exist com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.aad.AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure

I have newly created a spring boot project and added spring cloud and azure active directory and lots of dependency, now while I am trying to run my application I am getting below error.

Error:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
 
Description:
 
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
 
    com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.aad.AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:83)
 
The following method did not exist:
 
   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.client.OAuth2LoginConfigurer$AuthorizationEndpointConfig.authorizationRequestResolver(Lorg/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver;)Lorg/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/client/OAuth2LoginConfigurer$AuthorizationEndpointConfig;

The calling method's class, com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.aad.AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/ARIMO/.m2/repository/com/azure/spring/spring-cloud-azure-autoconfigure/4.5.0/spring-cloud-azure-autoconfigure-4.5.0.jar!/com/azure/spring/cloud/autoconfigure/aad/AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.client.OAuth2LoginConfigurer$AuthorizationEndpointConfig, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/ARIMO/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-security-config-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/client/OAuth2LoginConfigurer$AuthorizationEndpointConfig.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.client.OAuth2LoginConfigurer.AuthorizationEndpointConfig: file:/C:/Users/ARIMO/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-security-config-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.aad.AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.client.OAuth2LoginConfigurer$AuthorizationEndpointConfig

Process finished with exit code 1
```

POM.xml: Below is the pom file for integrate one of the functionalities of authenticate using active directory as well as other functionality.

```
project xmlns=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
       xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
       xsi:schemaLocation=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>com.demo.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>test</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <name>demo</name>
   <description>Spring boot project for test</description>

   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.1</version>
      <relativePath />
   </parent>

   <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      <cxf.version>3.1.5</cxf.version>
      <olingo.version>2.0.11</olingo.version>
      <commons.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</commons.version>
      <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
      <spring-cloud-azure.version>4.5.0</spring-cloud-azure.version>
   </properties>
  
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
         <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
      
     

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
         <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
               <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Cloud dependencies -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Cloud dependencies -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
               <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
      </dependency>



      <!-- Apache Olingo dependencies -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
         <artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-api</artifactId>
         <version>${olingo.version}</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
               <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
         <artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-core</artifactId>
         <version>${olingo.version}</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
               <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
         <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
         <version>${cxf.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
         <artifactId>olingo-odata2-api</artifactId>
         <version>${olingo.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
         <artifactId>olingo-odata2-core</artifactId>
         <version>${olingo.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
         <artifactId>olingo-odata2-api-annotation</artifactId>
         <version>${olingo.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Utilities -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
         <artifactId>flyway-sqlserver</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Test tools -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
         <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
         <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <version>1.18.10</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
         <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
         <version>3.4.10</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
         <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
         <version>0.9.8</version>
         <exclusions>

            <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.cloudfoundry.identity</groupId>
         <artifactId>cloudfoundry-identity-client-lib</artifactId>
         <version>4.10.0</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.json</groupId>
         <artifactId>json</artifactId>
         <version>20080701</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Utilities -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
         <version>2.13.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
         <version>2.13.2</version>

      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
         <version>2.13.2</version>

      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
         <version>2.13.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
         <version>2.13.2</version>

      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory</artifactId>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2021.0.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-azure.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Tried multiple times

Comment: Your error says: "Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.aad.AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.client.OAuth2LoginConfigurer$AuthorizationEndpointConfig", maybe you have a dependecy conflict? You can check this in "Analyze Dependencies..." on the maven tab in IntelliJ